# Problem with UIImageView loading via OperationQueue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, nsoperationqueue

I load a UIImageView using an NSOperationQueue.

The load fetches an image from the Internet and then adds it to an image view.  The problem I have is that the method finishes but it takes about 3 seconds later for the image view to actually either show the image or remove the image view from the superview...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { NSLog(@"AirportDetailView: viewDidLoad");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.activity startAnimating];
    self.queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadImage) object:NULL]; 
    [self.queue addOperation:operation]; 
    [operation release];
}

-(void)loadImage {
        [myAp ImageForAp];

        NSLog(@"ImageFor Ap Ended, %@",myAp.ApDiagram);

        [self.activity stopAnimating];

        if (myAp.ApDiagram==NULL) {
            NSLog(@"Finally Gets Here");
            [self.Diagram removeFromSuperview];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Finally Gets Here with Diag");
            [self.Diagram setBackgroundImage:myAp.ApDiagram forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

    }
```

The NSLOG shows a delay between the first two log statements of about 3 seconds can't understand why....

Updated with my Latest Code......

```
-(void)loadImage {

    [myAp ImageForAp];

    NSLog(@"ImageFor Ap Ended, %@",myAp.ApDiagram);

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(UpdateUI) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void)UpdateUI {

    [self.activity stopAnimating];

    if (myAp.ApDiagram==NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Finally Gets Here");
        [self.Diagram removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Finally Gets Here with Diag");
        [self.Diagram setBackgroundImage:myAp.ApDiagram forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `loadImage` method is being run on the main thread. All UI operations need to happen on the main thread to work as expected. Your code will need to look similar to this.

```
-(void)loadImage {
    [myAp ImageForAp];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(UpdateUI) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void)UpdateUI {
    [self.activity stopAnimating];

    if (myAp.ApDiagram==NULL) {
        [self.Diagram removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else {
        [self.Diagram setBackgroundImage:myAp.ApDiagram forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

There is also a possible memory leak inside of viewDidLoad.

`self.queue = [NSOperationQueue new];` should be changed to

`self.queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];`

Comment: Ok I took it off the main thread when I loaded it using an NS operation queue as the problem was that when I load the view it would stall the app during the navigation step prior to loading the view

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
 NSLog(@"AirportDetailView: viewDidLoad");
 [super viewDidLoad]; 
 
 [self.activity startAnimating];
 self.queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
 
 NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                   selector:@selector(loadImage) 
                     object:NULL];
 [self.queue addOperation:operation];
 [operation release];

Comment: You want all the of the downloading of the image to be done in the background (your NSOperation) but your code that controls the UI just needs to be moved to the main thread such as [self.activity stopAnimating]; There is an error in that code as well. Edit your original post and that code example and I will be able to update my answer.

Comment: Not sure how I can load the image without locking out the UI unless I use the operation queue.  the load step is done by another object called urlcache.   The problem is not the loading of the image but after it has been downloaded and just before the updates.

Comment: Should I attempt the uiupdate (remove from superview) on the main thread instead....

Comment: This is what should happen: viewDidLoad starts the Operation -> loadImage downloads the image -> at the end of loadImage call another method that updates the UI on the main thread.

Comment: Joe,  Thanks, that's exactly what I did but couldn't post my answer for 24 hours......  will post the code when I can..

Comment: You dont have to post that code as answer, edit your original question, then I will be able to edit my answer. If I helped you then marked my answer as correct, otherwise if it was something else that fixed your problem post your answer.

Comment: I edited my question to add the code I changed.  You noticed an Error, what was it...

Comment: Alright I edited my answer as well as your question to reflect what was discussed in these comments. The error was a potential memory leak that I point out in my updated answer.